# Would a magnet still work on the outside of an oil filter?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If I attach a magnet to the outside of an oil filter (aiming to trap small ferro-magnetic particles that would otherwise pass through the filter) would it work?

Yes I mean would the magnet still exhibit magnetic properties? and I posted here as it is an example of a principle of general physics  question.

If the concensus is positive then forum members may wish to stick their magnets thusly.

Comment: Do you mean would the magnet still exhibit magnetic properties?

Comment: Seems that this would be more appropriate on http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Long time since I did an oil change, but my sump plug was magnetic and it bristled with metal filings -- so yes, I think a strong magnet up against your oil filter will attract ferro-magnetic particles.

The bigger question might be where under the skin of the can will you find a vein/flow of oil worth screening?

My concerns then would be: What if the magnet attracted so much material that it would either block the flow through the filter or if "clots" of aggregated and now magnetized metal filings break away would it cause more damage to bushes and bearings than the individual filings would have?